# Match whole field in Lucene

Tags: php, zend-framework, lucene

I'm currently indexing a database with lucene. I was thinking of storing the table id in the index, but I can't find a way to retrieve the documents by that field. I guess some pseudo-code will further clarify the question:

```
document.add("_id", 7, Field.Index.UN_TOKENIZED, Field.Store.YES);
// How can I query the document with _id=7
// without getting the document with _id=17 or _id=71?
```

Comment: Which version of the Lucene API are you using?
Which method are you using (Document.add() takes a Fieldable, as of Lucene 2.4)?

Comment: I'm actually using the php port (provided by Zend) and wasn't aware that this could make a difference as the query syntax should be the same.

Comment: The query syntax is different. The principle remains. Being a port to php, Zend currently supports Lucene 2.3, which is about two versions behind the current Java Lucene version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT for Zend Lucene:
You will need a Keyword type field in order for it to be searched.
For indexing, use something like:

```
$doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::Keyword('_id', '7'));
```

For search, use:

```
$idTerm  = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Index_Term('_id', '7');
$idQuery = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_Query_Term($idTerm);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to say I've just implemented this successfully on my Zend Lucene search engine.  However, after some time troubleshooting I discovered that the field name and field value are the opposite way around to the way shown.  To correct the example:

```
// Fine - no change here
$doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::Keyword('_id', '7'));

// Reversed order of parameters
$idTerm  = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Index_Term('7', '_id',);
$idQuery = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_Query_Term($idTerm);
```

I hope that helps someone!